# How to create a Sip call using jain-sip api?

Tags: android, jain-sip

I have downloaded and imported jain sip api library in my project. However, I couldn't find any documentation or demo to create call via jain sip. All documentations I found are using messeges only. But I want to create a call using jain sip java api.

I want a good example or just the classes and methods to create a call(procedure). I am done with registration.

Comment: Hey @Khushal Chouhan i am trying same thing can.the below link is broken so please can show me or guid me how can i register sip acount and make call using jain sip ?

Comment: This may not be the exact answer you are looking for , but these guys seems to have made examples for most of the important things.
https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/blob/master/src/examples/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java.  and for a high level understanding start with this document https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jain-sip-tutorial-149998.pdf

Comment: once you gets to know what you are up against, to know your options use this 
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/enterprise-architecture/introduction-jain-sip-part1.html. 
if you are having trouble finding where to start, it's over here
https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip